# On "comment", @name sometimes does not work

Tags: bug, comments

Sometimes when I try to leave a comment the  @name  syntax does not work. For example I tried to leave a comment for Ulrike Fischer and I could not find a combination of characters that would work. I assumed I type @U and it will fill up the rest, but that does not work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You talk about the auto-completion of the user name in comments, right?
Could it be that you wanted to add a comment on one of Ulrike's posts?
The original poster of the post you comment on is always notified and the `@username` is even removed by the system if you use one and there were no comments of other people.

Anyway, the actual notification is independent on the auto-completion. You only need to type at least the first three letters of the name, so `@Ulr` would be technically enough. However, this always notifies the last user which commented on the same post which name starts with these letters. Note that spaces act as terminators, so `@UlrikeFischer` would be the safest and most correct way.